# How can I access the close/reopen/first-time-answer/low-quality queues on my phone?

Tags: discussion, review, user-interface, mobile

On my laptop, the menu with close votes, etc. is at the top right of the page, next to the notification and rep +/- icons. However, on my phone, only the notification and rep +/- icons appear. I can't find the open/close queues anywhere. Is there another way to access the open/close queues?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### You might be using the "mobile" version on your phone

The mobile version of the site does not include all the buttons in the top menu:

[image: mobile version]

Fortunately the "full version" of the site is responsive and perfectly usable on a phone and includes several additional options (including the review queues):

[image: full site]

To change to the full version you need to scroll all the way down to the footer and click on "full site" (meta and main site are separate so you may need to do this for each):

[image: full site option]

You may also need to "enable responsiveness", also in the footer.

[image: enable responsiveness, underneath help, chat, contact, and mobile]