# Theme of mobile site needs a bit of polish

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, site-design, mobile

I really like the theme of desktop site:

[image: Desktop]

The mobile site, on the other hand. Well, it is clean, and exceptionally generic shade of blue and gray:

[image: Mobile]

---

Would it be possible to, perhaps, just fix the color theme of mobile site to match the desktop version? Maybe even some font changes? That shouldn't be more than a few lines changed in CSS, right?

At least I find the difference jarring enough to make this meta post, and I might not be the only one who would enjoy a bit more personality :-D

Comment: You asked it and not me cuz I was afraid to ask...

Comment: @ThePuzzlerThree-TeamMonica I'm sorry to hear that you were afraid to ask! Please, if you ever have a question about site functionality, please feel free to ask it here, no need to be afraid :)

Comment: If I am on the mobile site (vs the app) I generally just bring up the options and click "Desktop site".

Comment: Marking this [status-declined] since staff have confirmed they're not updating the mobile site as Sdjz points out: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343179/404165

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The mobile version of the site won't be improved

On the main meta, there was a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343179/404165) by a staff member stating that there are plans to abandon the mobile version of the site in the future:

> We are actively working on the responsive design that works on both desktop and mobile, based on screen size. Once that is finished and perfected, mobile web will be slated for complete removal. While we still fix vital bugs for mobile web, you shouldn't expect any new features to be built for it.

### Try the Desktop version of the site instead

I already have [another answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8971/33707) detailing how to switch to the responsive desktop version on a mobile browser that you can check by selecting the "full site" option. This version has the same overall theme as the desktop site (after all it is the desktop site, just responsive to fit a smaller screen). I recommend giving it a try.

This version is not without its issues but given the above quote on the direction that the stack is taking, reporting any problems with the full site version when viewed on a smaller screen seems more likely to have an effect as this is the version that is being worked on.

Comment: Do note that there are *some* issues/differences with using the desktop site on mobile. The chat rooms get a bit wonky, related/linked questions are listed at the very bottom (instead of nowhere at all), and the timeline of a question is almost completely broken (nearly every line of text runs off into the edge of the screen)

Comment: @Medix2 I added a note to regard that. I still feel that even if there are some issues with the full site on mobile, reporting those issues is the way to go

Answer (score 5):

The “mobile” version of the website—the blue-and-white version that doesn't have our site theme—is not getting updated. It's deprecated and it's slated for completed removal ([staff post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343179/152515)).

This is because the main site itself—the themed version—is now mobile friendly. If it isn't already showing up that way you need to enable this behaviour:

1. Make sure you're on the desktop version of the site. If necessary, leave the blue-and-white mobile version by hitting the “full site” link in the footer.
2. Scroll down to the footer again.
3. Find the “Enable Responsiveness” link in the first section of the footer.
4. Hit that and wait for the page to reload.

The main site should then look like this on your phone. *This* is the current mobile view of the site.

[image: responsive main site in mobile view]

Comment: Actually there are 4 distinct ways to view the site on Android Chrome at least. Chrome checkbox "Desktop site" feature combined with site feature "full site"/"mobile". And "uncheck Desktop site"+"full site" is what I was after here.

Comment: Umm, and then there's this site feature "Enable/Disable responsiviness" for the "full site", making total 6 combinations. Fun.

Comment: Ah, except "responsiveness" seems to actually be the same as the Chrome setting, ie. if it is disabled, then Chrome "Desktop site" checkbox *seems* to have no effect. So just 4 modes after all, maybe.

Comment: Chrome's "view desktop site" checkbox just forces a much wider browser page and gives you a zoomed out view of it (among a handful of other technical behind-the-scenes things that won't mean much to explain). It doesn't have anything to do with the view modes on Stack Exchange. If you want to use responsive view here, switch it off.